# Floating figure breaking up theorem

Tags: floats, theorems

I have a floating figure that is currently splitting up a theorem when compiled, i.e., the figure is being inserted within the text/math describing the theorem. This makes for difficult parsing of the theorem. Is there any configuration of either the figure or the theorem such that the figure can remain floating *without* breaking up the theorem?

Comment: Could you post a small compilable code reproducing the problem?

Comment: use `\suppressfloats[t]` to stop top floats on the theorem page